# Pass params to inline import of webpack loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, create-react-app, worker-loader

I have a non-ejected create-react-app (react-scripts v3.4.3) and Typescript application that I am trying to use web workers in. I was able to get the worker bundled with [workerize-loader](https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader) using the following import statement:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import Worker from 'workerize-loader!./worker';
```

The issue is I need to change the publicPath property for the loader without ejecting from create-react-app so I tried adding query parameters as mentioned by the webpack documentation for [inline loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline):

> Options can be passed with a query parameter, e.g. ?key=value&foo=bar, or a JSON object, e.g. ?{"key":"value","foo":"bar"}

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import Worker from 'workerize-loader?publicPath="path/to/js/"!./worker';
```

I've tried both ways but both return the same Typescript compiler error of "Cannot find module..."

Are the query params mentioned in the webpack docs only meant for use in the `module.rules` property in `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually not related to Webpack at all but was a Typescript issue.

I am not sure if this is totally correct, but I will leave my solution for those trying to get `workerize-loader` working with create-react-app and Typescript.

I combined instructions from [worker-loader with Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-loader#integrating-with-typescript) and using the `publicPath` option (though not documented but in the [src](https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader/blob/master/src/index.js#L138)) of workerize-loader.

In my module declaration file I just declared the module with the `publicPath` value and then when I import the worker module I match the declaration. Assume these files are all located under a directory called `src/worker`. The last file shows how to invoke the worker method.

`src/worker/custom.d.ts`

```
declare module 'workerize-loader?publicPath=new/public/path/!*' {
  class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();

    // Add any custom functions to this class.
    // Make note that the return type needs to be wrapped in a promise.
    
    someLongOperation(): Promise<string>;
  }

  export = WebpackWorker;
}
```

`src/worker/index.ts`

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import Worker from 'workerize-loader?publicPath=new/public/path!./worker';

export default Worker;
```

`src/worker/worker.ts`

```
export function someLongOperation(): string {
  // doing long lasting operation
  // ...

  return 'result of long operation';
}
```

`src/someService.ts`

```
import Worker from 'src/worker';

...

const myWorker = new Worker();
cosnt workerResult = await myWorker.someLongOperation();
```

Comment: you probably want `declare module 'workerize-loader?*'` to capture any query.